# Where did the debug commands go in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

You're going to think I'm either lying or nuts, but neither is the case. I installed VS2008 PRO on a Windows 7 x64 machine and all the debugging commands are missing. There's no debug toolbar and no Debug.* commands under Tools\Options\keyboard.

How do I get the debug functionality working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't explain why it happened, but a full uninstall/reinstall fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try running this from the command line:

```
devenv /resetskippkgs
```

Comment: Sorry, Ben. That doesn't work either. It seems like the installer really didn't include any debugging related functionality. I'm going to try a reinstall.

Comment: Okay, hope the reinstall works for you.  If not post back and we'll get medieval on it.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you chose wrong presets when VS first started. I got that thing wrong too (or something just bugged..).

You can get them back (one by one) by right-clicking on a *toolbar* and choosing "Customize". There you can customize both toolbars and menus. You can also *drag* the commands onto both menus and toolbars. Commands are available in the second tab (going from memory here :) and are divided into several subcategories.

There are also several highly useful commands, like "Exceptions..." where you can finetune if and on which exceptions the integrated debugger will break immediately as they're thrown.

Comment: The toolbar Customize dialog doesn't contain a "Debug" category. So manually rebuilding the menus and toolbars won't work. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you installed the C# or C++ component then? The shell may be installed without these components and used for accessing TFS etc.

Comment: Yes, I really did install both C# and C++.